# Remove duplicate items from processes array using VB .net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have to code to get all accessible process, but I need to remove duplicated items on this array and show only one time each process.

How is the best method to do this, because I think processes array is not like a normal array.

My code:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    Try
        'MsgBox(p.ProcessName + " " + p.StartTime.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Do nothing
    End Try
Next
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think it's not like a normal array?  "An **array** of type Process that represents all the process resources running on the local computer." [Process.GetProcesses Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Process.GetProcesses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) method returns an array. You can use the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method, providing an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) to it.

An example would be as comparer:

```
Public Class ProcessComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Process)

    Public Function Equals1(p1 As Process, p2 As Process) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Process).Equals
        ' Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        If p1 Is p2 Then Return True
        'Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        If p1 Is Nothing OrElse p2 Is Nothing Then Return False
        ' Check whether the Process' names are equal. 
        Return (p1.ProcessName = p2.ProcessName)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(process As Process) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Process).GetHashCode
        ' Check whether the object is null. 
        If process Is Nothing Then Return 0
        ' Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        Return process.ProcessName.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Count before Distinct = {0}", processes.Length))

    ' Should contain less items
    Dim disProcesses As Process() = processes.Distinct(New ProcessComparer()).ToArray()
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Count after Distinct = {0}", disProcesses.Length))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

You probably have to refine the Comparer to your specifications and for the situation you are going to use it.